# Which Resharper setting causes backspace to remove the line break?

Tags: resharper

Resharper is interfering with my editing in a maddening way and I cannot figure out what setting to change to stop it.

If I hit backspace on a line when the cursor is *not* in the first column (and when there's only whitespace up to that column), instead of taking me back one space, it *completely removes the line break* and takes me back to the previous line.

To illustrate:  I've got a long-ish filter line that I want to make multiline.

```
    catch (Exception e) when (
        e is System.Data.DataException or System.Data.Common.DbException or Sdk.SdkException)
```

I want to make it look like this:

```
catch (Exception e) when (
    e is System.Data.DataException 
      or System.Data.Common.DbException
      or Sdk.SdkException)
```

So I put my cursor on the space just before the very first 'or' and hit ENTER.  That gives me this:

```
catch (Exception e) when (
    e is System.Data.DataException 
        or System.Data.Common.DbException or Sdk.SdkException)
       ^
       |
  CURSOR IS HERE
```

Now I try to hit backspace to align the 'or' with the 'is' but instead it removes the break. and takes me back to where I was.

I can work around it but I'd like to turn it off.  So far I've gone through most of the settings under these two sections, changing them one-by-one and changing them back.  Nothing seems to work.

```
Code Editing >> C#
    - Tabs, Indents, Alignment 
    - Line Breaks and Wrappin
```

Does anyone know what setting controls this?

Notes:

- I'm sure that this is Resharper because when I suspend it, this behavior stops.
- I'm using Resharper 2021.1.5
- I'm using Visual Studio 2019 16.10.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [Unindent code lines with Backspace](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Coding_Assistance_Typing_Assistance.html#unindenting-code-line-on-backspace).

Comment: Thank you.  I was looking in completely the wrong place!